# Why is my email EditText saving over my nickname EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm working my way through *"Sam's Tech Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours"* and at some point my Nickname and Email settings stopped saving correctly. It now doesn't save  the Nickname at all and saves the Email to both. What have I done to cause this, and how can I fix it?

I think that these are the relevant areas of the code, but if you need more please ask.
As far as I can tell, this is still code from the book, and it used to work.  Maybe a typo somewhere?

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs"; 
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME = null; //String
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL = null; //String

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    EditText nicknameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Nickname);
    EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Email);

    String strNickname = nicknameText.getText().toString();
    String strEmail = emailText.getText().toString();

    // TODO: fix password and email saving and displaying improperly
    Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
    editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME, strNickname);
    editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL, strEmail);
    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(QuizSettingsActivity.this, R.string.settings_saved,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void initNicknameEntry() {
    EditText nicknameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Nickname);
    if (mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME)) {
        nicknameText.setText(mGameSettings.getString(
                GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME, ""));
    }
}

public void initEmailEntry() {
    EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Email);
    if (mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL)) {
        emailText.setText(mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL,
                ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything you posted looks like, the problem is elsewhere. What are the values of `GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME` and `GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL`? Are they different Strings?

Comment: I updated the post to include part of the `GAME_PREFERENCES` @Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize these to distinct values:

```
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME = "Nickname"; //String
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL = "Email"; //String
```

Otherwise SharedPreferences cannot distinguish between the two keys and will always return the first key found.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find this. I had changed this away from the books code when I had problems implementing `reset()`.